# Is the following sequence a moment seqence?

Tags: moment-problem

Is the sequence
$$\Bigl( \frac{1}{n+1} \Bigr)^\alpha,\quad n \geq 0$$
a moment sequence for any $\alpha \in (0,1]$ for some random variable on [0,1]?

We have tried checking whether the corresponding matrix is positive definite, this did not show that it was not a moment sequence.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Yes, it is,  see  [Hausdorff moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_moment_problem).  Also, this follows from the fact that the function

$$ s \mapsto \frac{1}{(1+s)^{\alpha}}$$

is totally monotone ( [Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions)).

In fact you can produce a density on $[0,1]$ with its moment sequence the given one. You only need to find the [inverse Laplace transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5B1%2F%28EulerGamma%20%2B%20s%29%5ECatalan%2C%20s%2Ct%5D) of $\frac{1}{(1 + s)^{\alpha}}$.